# Apply CSS Style Up to the First Period in Every Element with a Certain Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, substring

I'm trying to apply CSS styles to all of the characters up to the first period in the text of every element with a certain class.

My initial attempt was to select the first 2 characters only, but that won't work if there are sub-items ( for example: "D (i)." and "D (ii)." )

**HTML**

```
    <div class="container content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 lefty">
                <div id="left-nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a class="nav-button active" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">A. Link 1</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-button" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">B. Link 2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-button" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">C. Link 3</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-button" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">D. Link 4</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-button" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">D(i). Link 4a</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-button" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">D(ii). Link 4b</span></a></li>
                        <li><a class="nav-button" href="#"><span class="menu-item-text">E. Link 5</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 righty">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan efficitur nunc, ut suscipit nisl. Phasellus vitae tellus a nunc feugiat commodo eget ac lorem. Vivamus dolor nulla, tempor a vulputate at, auctor ac ex. Praesent vestibulum lorem vitae lectus fringilla, vitae aliquet velit consequat. Mauris erat urna, dictum ut aliquam at, accumsan eget leo. Cras vel egestas arcu, quis scelerisque libero. Pellentesque vulputate varius scelerisque. Proin elementum urna vitae enim tincidunt, et commodo massa sagittis.</p>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed accumsan efficitur nunc, ut suscipit nisl. Phasellus vitae tellus a nunc feugiat commodo eget ac lorem. Vivamus dolor nulla, tempor a vulputate at, auctor ac ex. Praesent vestibulum lorem vitae lectus fringilla, vitae aliquet velit consequat. Mauris erat urna, dictum ut aliquam at, accumsan eget leo. Cras vel egestas arcu, quis scelerisque libero. Pellentesque vulputate varius scelerisque. Proin elementum urna vitae enim tincidunt, et commodo massa sagittis.</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Attempt at jQuery**

```
$(function () {

    var $str = $(".menu-item-text").slice(0, 2);

    $($str).css("font-weight", "bold");

});
```

**Fiddle:**  http://jsfiddle.net/jameelmoses/uo17qc94/12/

Comment: CSS is applied at the element level.  Wouldn't it be better to wrap the piece you want styled in <div> tags and set the class there?

Comment: Can't you give a different class for the sub-items? LIke `class="menu-item-subtext"`

Comment: Clarification: I'm not trying to use CSS to select the characters, I'm trying to use jQuery. I don't have control over the text to wrap it in a <span> or <div> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't target text nodes using CSS.

Your best option would be to add some markup around your numbers that you can then style.

If that isn't do-able, then you'll have to use JavaScript to go ahead and split the item by it's first period, wrap the first half in an element, I've gone for `span`. Join the parts together again, and apply your styles to the newly added `<span>`

```
// We'll use the .html() method, since it's the HTML we'll be changing
var $str = $(".menu-item-text").html(function(_,v){

  // Split initial value on the first period found
  var parts = v.split(/\.(.+)/);

    // Return new HTML, with item nos wrapped in a span
    return '<span class="some-class">' + parts[0] + '</span>.' + parts[1];
})
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uo17qc94/15/)

Comment: @Jameel Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
$(function () {

    $(".menu-item-text").each(function() {
       var $this = $(this);
        var str = $this.html();
        var index = str.indexOf(".");
        $this.html("<span class='some-class'>" + str.substring(0, index + 1) + "</span>" + str.substring(index + 1, str.length));
    });
});
```